# How to run java codes in XSLT 2.0 which were working fine in XSLT 1.0

Tags: java, oracle, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am upgrading the XSLT from 1.0 to XSLT 2.0,
It contains the java functions which were running successfully with version 1.0
But after changing the version to 2.0 getting the below error in Oxygen:

> Cannot find a 4-argument function named Q
> {http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/sunil.classic.aib.userfunctions.CustomExtensionFunctions}
> getSecondaryLineItems (). For diagnostics on calls to Java methods,
> use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property
> FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS

In eclipse I am getting below error while running Java:

> XML-23002: (Error) internal xpath error:
>
> oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber:
> 1; Start of root element expected.    at
> oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:326)     at
> oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:475)
> at
> oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:416)
> at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:247)     at
> oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:175)
> at
> oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:131)
> at com.bt.classic.provide.Provide.xmlBuild(Provide.java:71)     at
> com.bt.classic.provide.Provide.main(Provide.java:44)

This is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?oracle-xsl-mapper
  <!-- SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY. -->
  <mapSources>
    <source type="XSD">
      <schema location="BTOrderEntryReqResp.xsd"/>
      <rootElement name="ListOfBtorderentryreqigbl" namespace="http://www.siebel.com/xml/BTOrderEntryIGBL"/>
    </source>
  </mapSources>
  <mapTargets>
    <target type="XSD">
      <schema location="GlobalInteraction_Inter.xsd"/>
      <rootElement name="BatchLoadOrder" namespace="GlobalInteraction.xsdobjects.extload.services.classic.bt.inter"/>
    </target>
  </mapTargets>
  <!-- GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 10.1.3.3.0(build 070615.0525) AT [FRI AUG 10 16:02:57 IST 2012]. -->
?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:sunil="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/sunil.classic.aib.userfunctions.CustomExtensionFunctions"
exclude-result-prefixes="xp20 xsl">

        <tns:ActivationDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="xp20:current-dateTime()"/>
        </tns:ActivationDate>
...........
.............
.........

<!--****Problem is with the below code while changing the version of XSLT from 1.0 to 2.0
sunil:getSecondaryLineItems is the java function which is inside java file
****-->

<xsl:variable name="SecondaryLineItems"
                              select="sunil:getSecondaryLineItems($totalLineItems,$lineItemsWithoutRW,$lineItemsWithRW,$rootelement)"/>
                <!-- Changes done for BW110776 -->
                <xsl:variable name="PrimaryLineItems"
                              select="sunil:getPrimaryLineItems($totalLineItems,$SecondaryLineItems[not(wiz:Product='IP Connect global SLA')],$rootelement2)"/>

............
...........

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what xslt implementation are you using?

Comment: sorry I am not getting your question, actually everything was working fine if XSLT version was 1.0 but after changing the version with 2.0 I am getting errors. Is there any way to fix this

Comment: There is no standardized way for an XSLT processor use Java, most Java implementations of XSLT can do that but the way to do it might be rather product specific. So, at least inside of oXygen, you should be able to see/tell which XSLT processor exactly you have used for XSLT 1 and which one for XSLT 2. For XSLT 2 oXygen tends to use Saxon Java and usually offers, for one particular main release, all three editions HE, PE and EE. Only the last two ones allow "reflexive" calls into Java. On the other hand, if you have Oracle specific extension code, better ask Oracle support.